# What is the difference between model.to(device) and model=model.to(device)?

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose the model is originally stored on CPU, and then I want to move it to GPU0, then I can do:

```py
device = torch.device('cuda:0')
model = model.to(device)
# or
model.to(device)
```

What is the difference between those two lines?

Comment: If my answer looks good to you, please accept it :)

Answer (score 85):

No semantic difference. `nn.Module.to` function moves the model to the device.

But be cautious.

For tensors ([documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to)):

```
# tensor a is in CPU
device = torch.device('cuda:0')
b = a.to(device)
# a is still in CPU!
# b is in GPU!
# a and b are different
```

For models ([documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.to)):

```
# model a is in CPU
device = torch.device('cuda:0')
b = a.to(device)
# a and b are in GPU
# a and b point to the same model
```

Comment: [Updated Link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.to). For `nn.Module`, "This method modifies the module in-place."

Comment: In other words, `b = a.to(device)` for a model `a` is probably confused coding and should rather just be `a.to(device)`, while `a.to(device)` for a tensor `a` has no effect at all?

Comment: So how do I move a module _not_ in place? Create a copy and move that copy?

Comment: @roygbiv ``copied_model = copy.deepcopy(model)`` should do the trick.

Answer (score 19):

Citing the documentation on `to`:

> When loading a model on a GPU that was trained and saved on GPU,
>   simply convert the initialized model to a CUDA optimized model using
>   `model.to(torch.device('cuda'))`. Also, be sure to use the
>   `.to(torch.device('cuda'))` function on all model inputs to prepare
>   the data for the model. Note that calling `my_tensor.to(device)`
>   returns a new copy of `my_tensor` on GPU. It does NOT overwrite
>   `my_tensor`. Therefore, remember to manually overwrite tensors:
>   `my_tensor = my_tensor.to(torch.device('cuda'))`.

Mostly, when using `to` on a `torch.nn.Module`, it does not matter whether you save the return value or not, and as a micro-optimization, it is actually better to not save the return value. When used on a torch tensor, you must save the return value - seeing you are actually receiving a copy of the tensor.

Ref: [Pytorch to()](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-on-gpu-load-on-cpu)