# PyTorch CUDA: "to(device)" vs "device=device" for tensors?

Tags: python, pytorch

I found a somewhat similar question here [What is the difference between model.to(device) and model=model.to(device)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560043/what-is-the-difference-between-model-todevice-and-model-model-todevice), but I would like to check again if the same applies to my example:

1. Using `.to(self.device)`

```
mask = torch.tril(torch.ones(len_q, len_k)).type(torch.BoolTensor).to(self.device)`
```

and

2. Using `device=self.device`

```
mask = torch.tril(torch.ones((trg_len, trg_len), device = self.device)).bool()
```

Are they both accomplishing the same thing - ensuring that `mask` goes to the GPU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`torch.Tensor.to`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.to.html) function will make a copy of your tensor on the destination device. While setting the `device` option on initialization will place it there on init, so there is no copy involved.

So in your case you would rather do:

```
>>> mask = torch.tril(torch.ones(len_q, len_k), device=self.device)
```

But to give an answer to your question, both have the effect of placing `mask` on `self.device`. The only difference is that in the former you will have a copy of your data on both devices.

---

The same can be said for `torch.Tensor.bool` *vs.* initializing with `dtype`:

```
>>> torch.randint(0, 1, (10,)).bool()
```

Will make a copy, while the following won't:

```
>>> torch.randint(0, 1, (10,), dtype=torch.bool)
```

However, [`torch.tril`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tril.html) doesn't provide a `dtype` option, so it is not relevant here.

Comment: So the second option ` device = self.device` is always the best way to go?

Comment: If you know where your tensor is meant to go, then initializing on the correct machine is always preferable.