# PyTorch model deletion doesn't free up memory even after deletion, gc call and emptying cache

Tags: python, pytorch, garbage-collection

I encountered some weird behaviour with `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`, `to(device)` and `gc.collect()`. In short, deletion of model can not work is some specific scenarios. Lets say I'm creating a model, sending it to GPU, and after that deleting it.

```py
import gc
import torch
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
print(device)
> 'cuda'

def memReport():
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if torch.is_tensor(obj):
            print(type(obj), obj.size(), obj.device)

import torch.nn as nn

class WordPredictionLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers):
        super(WordPredictionLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        embedded = self.embedding(x)
        lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(embedded)
        logits = self.fc(lstm_out[:, :, :])
        return logits

# big params for easier test
vocab_size = 100 
embedding_dim = 4000
hidden_dim = 2560
num_layers = 10

memReport()
> 'emptry output'

model = WordPredictionLSTM(vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers)
model = model.to(device)

memReport()
> 'lots of parameter objects, all in cuda:0'

del model
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()

memReport()
> 'emptry output'
```

So far, so good. Now, let's switch `model = model.to(device)` to just `model.to(device)`. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560043/what-is-the-difference-between-model-todevice-and-model-model-todevice) and PyTorch docs, calling ".to()" from module object moves it to desired device kinda in-place, so the call should move model to GPU. Which is true, calling `memReport()` after creating model shows that all params are on cuda:0.

For example, one string: `<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'> torch.Size([100, 4000]) cuda:0`.

The problem arises then I try to delete this model. Using the same sequence of `del + gc.collect() + torch.cuda.empty_cache()` now does nothing. All parameters still are in `gc` list, I see some memory freeing, but totally not all of it, if I use `torch.cuda.memory_reserved(0), torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0)` I see that `del+collect+empty` clears some reserved memory but does nothing to allocated one. Creating model again would take even more space, it takes more and more memory with each creation. The weirdest part, I don't even have variables connected to these models, which take memory, since each creation creates new object, so even if `.to(device)` method would not modify model, each creation of new model should result in old model being unreferenced, so it should be collected by garbage collector, but for some reason that doesn't happen.

Can anyone explain, what's going on here, am I doing something wrong or this is just specifics of `.to(device)` method and I should never call it without assigning result to some variable?

For additional info, I work in jupyter notebook, pytorch version is 2.0.1, python version is 3.8 (chosen randomly)